Import graphviz throwing ModuleNotFoundError when I import graphviz in python(ipynb)
I am trying to import Graphviz in vs-code jupyter but its throwing a ModuleNotFoundError.
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 import graphviz
      2 print(graphviz.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'

I have installed graphviz in windows and added it to my env path.
I have tried checking dot -V and it does work and show the version.
The error.
I have tried to pip install graphviz, but it still import graphviz and shows an error.
Code Snippet
I have rechecked my path in env
Environment variables

You must be running your script in a different environment / python version to the one where you installed...

Try %pip install pygraphviz as a command in your notebook. This will ensure you're installing into the same python environment the notebook is running.

I only have 1 one Python version: python 3.12.
I have used pip using the vscode terminal as well to install it in the same environment.

Despite your insistence, if you cannot import it, you didn't install it in the environment where Jupyter's kernel is accessing. Jupyter handles things very differently than the system Python and you need to make these connections if you aren't going to do with something that handles it for you, like choosing the Anaconda Distribution. Running %pip list in your running Jupyter notebooks should show what it can see installed. The magic symbol means something special as David Waterworth is trying to point out to you. And David's advice is the best if you don't mind yet installing it ...

yet again. It is the easiest way past such hurdles if you don't want to go establishing the connections you need at this point.
